# how do i get the number of members on status name

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I have a `member` Table with `member_Id`

a `mmship` table with columns `mmshipstart date` and `member_Id` and `mshipstatus_Id`

another table  `mshipstatustype` with columns `mshipstatus_Id` and `mshipstatus_name`

I have got `mshipstatus_name` row value is `prospective`......

how do  i get the number of `members(count)`  per month  those are having `mshipstatusname` is `prospective`

can i get the count starting from `mmshipstart date` .

would any one help me out...

I am new to joins would any one pls help....

Comment: -1 Your question is not very clear, and you are not helping with your description, try laying out some of the data formatted as code, then write some of the desired output format also as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM member inner join mmship
   ON member.member_Id = mmship.member_Id
   INNER JOIN mshipstatus
   ON mshipstatus.mshipstatus_Id = mmship.mshipstatus_Id
WHERE mshipstatus.mshipstatusname = 'prospective'
   AND MONTH(mmship.mmshipstart_date) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

(you can change the getdate() with another date).

Comment: I ahve a doubt, is it date of month starting from mmshipstart_date

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean, could you expain your comment?

Comment: I want to get the count those who hav prospect and the date starting from mship_startdate

Comment: but where do you get the date to check against the mshipstart_date?

Answer (score 0):

Does

`select count(*) as prospective from mshipstatustype t1 join mmship t2 where 
t1.mshipstatus_id=t2.mshipstatus_id and t2.mshipstatus_name="prospective" group by
year(mmshipstart_date), month(mmshipstart_date)`

Do what you want?